# How is the extension of the spring equal 2 times the extension of the block

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

[image]

This is related to a question given to me in class by my teacher. The question if it helps was :

> To find the time period of the simple harmonic motion performed by the block, if it is displaced slightly from its mean position

So, my teacher in his solution wrote a line that I couldn't understand. The statement was as follows :

> Let the extension of the spring be $x_p$ and let the block displace $x_o$ meters downwards.
> And $\displaystyle{x_o = \frac{x_p + 0}{2} }$

**But shouldn't it be $\displaystyle{x_o = \frac{x_p+x_p}{2}}$
Since if the spring extends $x_p$ meters downwards the string must also displace by the same amount downwards ?**

Comment: Length of the string is constant.In order to move pulley by x , spring has to be extended by 2x

Comment: Could you please elaborate ?

Comment: Because the center of the pulley goes down by x, and you have 2 contact points with ceiling, this means that each side needs to also extend by x, meaning that total length change spring+rope is 2x, but as rope has constant length, than spring suffers the full extension of 2x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your teacher has done is correct.
Forget the spring for a second and think of this as one complete string with both ends attached to the roof.Then for every 2 units of length the string stretches the block will move only by one unit.This happens as the extension of the extensible string will be  equally divided along the two sides.

In your problem the string doesn't stretch, but that same principle applies as your spring can extend.

[image: Diagram]

Answer (score 0):

Let the length of spring before displacement be Ls and length of string be L. Therefore, length of one side ( right and left ) of this arrangement is $(Ls+L)/2$.

Now, if spring extends by length xp, then length of combination is Ls+L+xp. This will also get divided into two as there are two sides. Therefore, now the length of one side is $(Ls+L+xp)/2$.

The change in length would give $xp/2$ which is the displacement of the block.

I hope this makes things clearer.

Comment: Initially the spring is going to be extended by some amount due to the weight of the block and the pulley.So the length of one side you have given is wrong as you have considered the natural length of the spring.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I edited it ;)

Answer (score 0):

[image] [image]

**$\left[\color{blue}{y\le \dfrac{x+y}{2}\le x}\right]\ \ \  \forall \ \ x\ge y$**

Notice, as a **Thumb Rule**, the vertical displacement $d$ (upward or downward) of the center of any pulley having vertical displacements $\color{red}{x}$ & $\color{blue}{y}$ of both the ends of an extensible string wound around it is always $d=\dfrac{\color{red}{x}+\color{blue}{y}}{2}$

As per given question, let $x$ be the extension of spring i.e. vertical (downward) displacement of one end of (inextensible) string. The other end of string is attached to the stationary support i.e. it can't be displaced hence the displacement of other end will be zero i.e. $y=0$. Therefore, the vertical downward displacement of center of pulley i.e. the vertical downward displacement of block attached to the center of pulley is given as
$$d=\frac{x+0}{2}=\frac x2$$
$$x=2d$$
Above result shows that the extension of spring $x$ is twice the vertical downward displacement of block attached to the center of pulley.